# Checking audio output levels per channel in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

I've got a new 5.1 channel headset, and am in the process of testing and adjusting it. How can I check the output levels per channel? I'd also be interested in seeing a breakdown of the output by frequency (i.e. frequency spectrum). My audio card driver doesn't seem to provide any way to see these things (VIA HD Audio Deck).